# How to compute distance formula between a 1d and an nd array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I am trying to subtract a 1d array:

```
probe = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

from each element in an nd array:

```
k = np.array([["words words ", 1,1,3,4,6,7], ["blah blah", 2,8,7,5,3,2], [" please help me", 3,4, 5, 6, 7,1], [" What are you doing, man", 1,3,5,10,9,11]])
```

I have deleted the 0th index of the k array and stored those values in new_k so that the comparison is now between the values in both of the arrays I want to compare.

```
new_k = k
new_k = np.delete(new_k, 0, axis=1)
```

I am trying to find the value in the nd array that is closest to the input.I need help.

So far I've managed to get to here, but I am lost.:

```
for i in range(len(new_k)):
    for j in range(len(new_k[0][1])):
        temp[j] = (new_k[1][j] - probe[j])
        new_k[i][1] = temp

print(new_k)
new_k2 = new_k*new_k
```

the above code throws this error :

```
TypeError: ufunc 'subtract' did not contain a loop with signature matching types dtype('<U32') dtype('<U32') dtype('<U32')
```

also: I know how to get a "closest value to" by comparing a single value to an array of values, but I want to do that with arrays to arrays

Comment: can you please paste the full code. As new_k is saying unknown.

Comment: where is your new_k?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Numpy arrays are not meant to have multiple data types. `k` is actually an array of strings, so there are no numeric data types to subtract in your array `k`.

If you would like to keep your first column of strings, you should look at pandas dataframes. You can keep the string as your index of the dataframe but still operate on it as an array of numeric data. With your data, you can do something like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(k[:, 1:].astype(int), index=k[:, 0])
df - probe
```

Answer (score 0):

```
np.asarray(k[:,1:], dtype=int) - probe
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that numpy is not like a normal list and it holds only unique type elements at a time. If there is more than 1 type all are converted into `U32` which is a `string`. When you remove the 1st element from the list the rest are still string type, not int. You should have converted them to `int`. And therefore this error raises:

```
TypeError: ufunc 'subtract' did not contain a loop with signature matching types dtype('<U32') dtype('<U32') dtype('<U32')
```

when you try this:

```
temp[j] = (new_k[1][j] - probe[j])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
In [263]: probe = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

`k` has a `dtype` that accomodates the strings:

```
In [264]: k = np.array([["words words ", 1,1,3,4,6,7], ["blah blah", 2,8,7,5,3,2
     ...: ], [" please help me", 3,4, 5, 6, 7,1], [" What are you doing, man", 1
     ...: ,3,5,10,9,11]])
In [265]: k
Out[265]: 
array([['words words ', '1', '1', '3', '4', '6', '7'],
       ['blah blah', '2', '8', '7', '5', '3', '2'],
       [' please help me', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '1'],
       [' What are you doing, man', '1', '3', '5', '10', '9', '11']],
      dtype='<U24')
```

But by slicing off the first column, the rest can be converted to an integer array:

```
In [266]: k[:, 1:].astype(int)
Out[266]: 
array([[ 1,  1,  3,  4,  6,  7],
       [ 2,  8,  7,  5,  3,  2],
       [ 3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  1],
       [ 1,  3,  5, 10,  9, 11]])
```

That's a (4,6) array.  `np.array(probe)` is (6,); broadcasting lets us subtract that:

```
In [270]: k[:, 1:].astype(int) - np.array(probe)
Out[270]: 
array([[ 0, -1,  0,  0,  1,  1],
       [ 1,  6,  4,  1, -2, -4],
       [ 2,  2,  2,  2,  2, -5],
       [ 0,  1,  2,  6,  4,  5]])
```